# Is there any result on the homomorphic images of hypercube graphs?

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, hypercube

Let $Q_n$ be a [hypercube graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypercube_graph) and $\phi: Q_n\to G$ a surjective simplicial graph morphism i.e. if $u,v$ are adjacent vertices in $Q_n$ then either $\phi(u)=\phi(v)$ or $\phi(u),\phi(v)$ are adjacent. Is there any intrinsic characterization of graphs $G$ which can be the image of such a map?

Comment: If you consider the vertices of $Q_n$ as binary strings, you can map all the strings of the same weight (number of 1's) together to create a path. A homomorphic image of a path can be anything, so you can get any graph as a homomorphic image of $Q_n$ if you do not restrict $n$. If $n$ is fixed then it is not so clear. [Here is a paper](https://www3.nd.edu/~dgalvin1/pdf/homomorphismstoZ.pdf) about homomorphisms from $Q_n$ to the infinite path, but they are focused on the diameter of the image, which may not be useful to you. Also, they don't allow adjacent vertices to be mapped together.

Comment: The fixed $n$ question actually seems more natural in the reverse direction:  For any graph $G$, we can define the "hypercube number" (for lack of a better term) as the smallest $n$ for which the graph is a homomorphic image of $Q_n$.  What can be said about the hypercube number of a graph, and can it be bounded in terms of other graph properties?

Comment: Your question is unclear to me: I think $u$ and $v$ should be vertices of $Q_n$, not $G$? Can you clarify the properties of the morphism you are looking for? It seems not to be a standard graph homomorphism.

Comment: @DavidE.Roberson I'm not sure I understand your comment. Yes a homomorphic image of a path can be anything but being inside a cube puts further restrictions on the image. For example you can map a spanning path in a 3-cube to a heptagon but the adjacency relations imposed by the cube and the definition of a graph map imply that the image cannot be longer than a 4-cycle.

Comment: Or in other words: what about the vertices that are not in the path?

Comment: @RezaRezazadegan I do not mean that if you map a path from within an $n$-cube to a graph then it can be extended to the whole $n$-cube. As you point out, that is not always possible. What I meant is that you can map the entire $n$-cube to a path (of length $n$). Since the homomorphic image of a path can be anything, you can compose the map from the cube to the path with the map from the path to the anything to obtain a map from the cube to the anything.